# I am looking for alternative contract of ERC721URIStorage.sol to be compatible for ERC1155

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, erc-1155

I am looking for a replacement of ERC721 with ERC1155 contracts from openzapplin, what do I need to keep in the place of ERC721URIStorage.sol.